# Can I have a 2 column sortable jquery drag/drop without jqueryUI?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to do a basic 2 column wide sortable drag/drop list with jquery, WITHOUT using jqueryUI?

I would like to make something more lightweight but still use jquery.  All I need is drag/drop capabilities, which sortable function works perfect but I need to be able to have 2 columns act as 1 unit, so a serialized list will show the order for both columns together

Here is somewhat of an example of what I need but this version is using jqueryUI

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/empty-lists.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that you can just select the components from jQuery UI want, right?  You can download the individual components and put them on the page.  You'd only need UI Core, Draggable, and Droppable ~ 34K minified.  Another alternative is loading jQuery UI from the [Google content network](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/), which case the user may already have it loaded making the download size immaterial.

Comment: 130K just seems huge to me, I think that double jquery itself

Comment: Yeah -- actually that's the size for the entire jQuery UI.  Core + Draggable + Droppable is more like 34K.  I'll update.